# Adding media to Twilio group messaging system

Tags: php, twilio

My group messaging app allowing people in a group (people.php) to sms each other in a closed system where all users can view and reply to the sms.

My next step would be to allow the media files which I can see on the Twilio Console to be sent to others in this group message system and possibly save a record of that media file.

This my code so far, it functions just missing the media part.

listener.php

```
<?php
include("../Services/Twilio.php");
include("config.php");
$client = new Services_Twilio($accountsid, $authtoken);
include("functions.php");
include("pdo.class.php");
include("people.php");


if( isset($_POST['Body']) ){
    $phone = $_POST['From'];    
    $message = ($_POST['Body']);
    $media = ($_POST['MediaUrl0']);

    $name = $people[ $phone ];
    if( empty($name) )  $name = $phone;

    // resends sms message to group
    $message = '['.$name.'] '.$message .$media;
    foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
        if( $number == $phone ) continue;
        $sid = send_sms($number,$message,$media);
    }

    // reply message for succesfull sent sms
    print_sms_reply("Message delivered");

    // insert sms traffic into database for record purposes
    $now = time();
    $pdo = Db::singleton();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO message_log SET `message`='{$message}', `sent_from`='{$name}'";
    $pdo->exec( $sql );
}

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php
    function send_sms($number,$message){
        global $client,$fromNumber;
        $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
            $fromNumber, 
            $number,
            $message
        );
        return $sms->sid;
    }

    function print_sms_reply ($sms_reply){
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";    
        echo "<Response>\n<Sms>\n";
        echo $sms_reply;
        echo "</Sms></Response>\n";
    }
?>
```

people.php

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $conn=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname")
    or die (mysqli_error());
    $query = "SELECT phone, name FROM grouplist";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $people = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $people[$row['phone']] = $row['name'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, what is the problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying to get the   MediaUrl0  and forward it to people in the Group as I did with From and Body.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you need to update your `send_sms` function to include the media url. Something like this should work:

```
<?php
    function send_sms($number,$message,$media_url){
        global $client,$fromNumber;
        $sms = $client->account->messages->create(array( 
            'To' => $number, 
            'From' => $fromNumber, 
            'Body' => $message, 
            'MediaUrl' => $media_url
        );
        return $sms->sid;
    }
?>
```

Notably, I've updated the call from `$client->account->sms_messages->create` because the `sms_messages` resource is deprecated and cannot send media messages. Using `$client->account->messages->create` uses the newer [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and means you will be able to send media messages.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: The main idea is that I am trying to grab the media files i.e. photos taken from users of the group messaging system.  Then allow other users to view these photos with the sms message.

Comment: That's what I thought. Does my update to your `send_sms` function not help?

Comment: Yes It works better I find but the Media URL is not found

Comment: Ok, can you explain that a bit more. Where is the Media URL not found? Are you not receiving it in the HTTP request? Are you finding the URL returns a 404? Do you have a URL but find it's not sent with the REST API request? Have you done any more debugging?